# Strange Behaviour of Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using twitter bootstrap to design the site. I have taken time to make the site responsive. The problem is when I resize the browser, the site becomes responsive but sometimes when resized and then again maximize the display is still in resize mode. Have attached the screenshots for better understanding.

[image: Before minimize] 
[image: After maximize]
[image: Another case of maximize]

Does anyone else experience this strange behaviour of bootstrap?
P.S All the screenshots are taken in browser maximize mode.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the browser isn't rendering properly on viewport change. I used to have the same problem once but wasn't able to figure out the reason. However, I used to hit a refresh (F5) on each resize to force responsify it.

Comment: Unfortunately even when i hit refresh its the same result. May be i have to try something else